# Magento 2 on docker generated files' user and permissions Mgt Development Environment

Tags: docker, permissions, magento2

I'm trying out MGT Development Environment 7.0 and installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.

every time after `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, and reload the page, generated files in `var`, `pub`, `generated` have different user and group `clp:clp`.

Instead of running `chmod -R 777 .` every time.  Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After view `phpinfo()`, found out that php in running by user `clp`

Simply `chown` the webroot `clp:clp` and everytime run php command by `sudo -u clp php yourCommand`, which solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you it worked even without chown, i used only this command "sudo -u clp php "